# Can I find particular someone's all reply or comment on any photo/video/posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

Just like my title, I have tried someway to do this. All I can find is like https://www.stalkscan.com or Graph API Explorer. But still can't find some particular user's comment on all Facebook posts. Can somebody tell us how to find it?